# unresolved external symbol fabs, cos, sin

Tags: c++, c++11, math, visual-c++

EDIT2: problem solved with adding libucrt.lib to link options

I'm trying to compile resource only DLL-file with VisualC++ 2017 compiler. Here is my command line:

```
cl test.cpp /link /dll /noentry "E:\CXGE\build\Debug\CXGE.lib"
```

Test.cpp contains some basic functions and math operations. But for some reason I can't use any of c++ math functions like std::sin, std::cos and std::abs in my DLL file because of this linking error:

```
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fabs referenced in function "double __cdecl abs(double)" (?abs@@YANN@Z)
```

Can someone say which libraries do I need to link to fix these errors? I'm on Windows 10, using Visual C++ 2017 compiler

EDIT: I am using X64 Native tools command prompt for VS 2017

Comment: Did you by any chance omit the `std::` from their name?

Comment: nope, i always use std:: before those

Comment: Add the switch to include the appropriate CRT see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx

Comment: okay thanks, problem is fixed with adding libucrt.lib to linker options

Answer (score 0):

These functions are in the math library. Under Linux, you'd typically link this just by adding '-lm' to the compilation line. I'm not sure of the equivalent for VC++, but hopefully it's something similar.

Comment: I can see two indicators in OPs question that it is not a Linux environment.

Comment: yeah i know, its easy fix under linux :(

Answer (score 0):

C Runtime libraries are missing. Either include them or try to compile using VS command prompt.

Comment: yeah solved it with adding libucrt.lib to linker params :D